# Early 20th Century Vienna - memoirs of Travelers

Tags: 20th-century, 19th-century, austria, travel

I am searching for memoirs of travelers who went to Vienna in 1900-1913. What they saw and did, where they ate etc  and am having a hard time finding anything.

Comment: I had an equally hard time. I did find that Mary Shelley [wrote a travelogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rambles_in_Germany_and_Italy) that included the area in the 1840's, but she didn't actually go through Vienna itself. Closest she got was Linz. If nobody else comes up with anything, I'd highly suggest asking your local head librarian. This kind of question is their bread-and-butter.